# AngularJS / Ionic "Uncaught TypeError: angular.moule is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

Estou iniciando com Ionic / AngularJS e estou criando uma função para exibir um alerta, com o intuito de checar se o "ambiente" está correto. Porém ao iniciar o APP verifico no console que está gerando a seguinte falha "Uncaught TypeError: angular.moule is not a function at core.js:1"

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>  
      ...  
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="assets/js/core.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
         <app-root></app-root> 
     </body> 
   </html>
```

page.html

```
<ion-content>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <button ng-click="clickFunction()">Click me!</button>
    </div>     
</ion-content>
```

core.js

```
var app = angular.moule('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickFunction = function() {
        alert("Clicado");
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, tá escrito **moule** ali se não percebeu, tanto no erro e no código. Creio que ele só está reclamando que este não é um método valido, substitua por `angular.module` no `core.js`. Recomendo usar um editor melhor xD

Comment: Estou usando o VSC e ficou na cor correta. Aproveitando.. Alterei o nome, e agora a mensagem de erro não aparece. Mas o alerta não aparece.

Comment: Porque está usando angularJS no ionic?

Comment: Estou iniciando, estudando e trabalhando em uma idéia para um APP.. o que você indicaria para desenvolver no Ionic? Posso te mostrar o projeto